# JAVA program output difference between Travis CI and Locally run on a windows laptop

Tags: java, travis-ci

I have these lines of Java code which converts a `Date` object to 10 digit `Integer`

```
SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyddMM");
Integer dateIntFormat = DATE_FORMAT.parse("20100405").getTime() / 1000;
```

When I run the above code on my laptop locally I get

```
dateIntFormat = 1272927600;
```

But when the same code is run on Travis I get

```
dateIntFormat = 1272931200;
```

Can anyone explain why, and how to fix it on my local machine?

Comment: Looks like you have different timezone settings on your laptop and on the CI server. The number you're getting includes the time, which is different in different timezones. The best way to solve this depends on why exactly you need this integer.

Comment: `yyyyddMM` is a useless, non-standard, non-sortable date format. Are you ***sure*** this is correct?

Comment: @yole I am working on getting json data from a REST API. The REST API I am using converts date to a 10 digit Integer and uses that to get data from a specific day. I think the timezones might be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with adding timezone information:

```
DATE_FORMAT.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("TIME_ZONE"));
```

You can find out available time zone in java like this:

```
String[] ids = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
```